# scrolling changes the size of the ice datatable headers

Tags: icefaces

It seems like a bug in icefaces. Most of the forums(in 2008/9, I could not find any recent answers in forums) says some solutions to over come this, but none of them give a solution which we can add columns widths as percentages. So what I like to know is, is there a way that we can over come this.

Description of the problem
 When we add a scroll to a datatable, the headers widths become mess. And there's a solution that we can add fixed widths in pixel (columnWidths attribute). But it is not supported in percentage. So I am asking is there a better solution for this. Because I want the datatable widths to be changed from screens to screen(different sizes)

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a profile of column widths to match the entities that you want to display in your backing bean.

As icefaces does not support the column widths yet.

http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_1/tld/index.html